# Using a random seed in Rmallet

Tags: r, topic-modeling, mallet

Is there an option (or a workaround) in Rmallet to use a random seed, as is possible through the mallet command line (i.e. --random-seed 1)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, via the rJava interface to the underlying `ParallelTopicModel.setRandomSeed` method (see [here](http://mallet.cs.umass.edu/api/cc/mallet/topics/ParallelTopicModel.html#setRandomSeed%28int%29))

```
library(mallet)
library(rJava)
m <- MalletLDA(num.topics=20, alpha.sum=5, beta=0.1)
m$model$setRandomSeed(42L)
```

The seed has to be an explicit integer (hence the `L` in `42L`).
If you are using the development version of RMallet from github, you'd need

```
m$setRandomSeed(42L)
```

Comment: Great answer; thanks a bunch! m$model$setRandomSeed(42L) worked great as long as it was called before documents were loaded.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it worked. You're right about setting the seed before loading documents. I had to look at [the source](https://github.com/mimno/Mallet/blob/master/src/cc/mallet/topics/ParallelTopicModel.java#L224) to understand why there was any randomness there: the initial random assignment of tokens to topics is done when you load documents.